# Delete and add attributes with array.map and the spread operator

Tags: ecmascript-2016

I'm trying to mangle data returned from an api. I've got an array of objects returned. I want to delete the password field and then add a couple of additional fields. I'd like to use the spread operator but my process feels a bit clunky.

```
myArray.map( item => {
    const newItem = { ...item };
    delete newItem.password;
    newItem.saved = true;
    return newItem;
});
```

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of objects -

```
const myArrayOfObjects = [
    {id: 1, keyToDelete: 'nonsense'},
    {id: 2, keyToDelete: 'rubbish'}
];
```

Delete the attribute `keyToDelete`, and add a new key `newKey` with the value `"someVar"`.

```
myArrayOfObjects.map(({ keyToDelete, ...item}) => { ...item, newKey:'someVar'});
```

Updating the array to

```
[
    {id: 1, newKey:'someVar'},
    {id: 2, newKey:'someVar'}
]
```

See [this great post](https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90) for more information on the deletion method.